# communication to sharepoint server talking too long

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, office365

In my case am the one terminating the connection by closing the authentication popup because it takes too long . I can browser the site url but i can't authenticate myself on visual studio It was working few days ago but now it gets stuck on that consent for like forever .

[image]

- visual studio 2017
- server connection: online
- start action: chrome
- host: sharepoint

If you have any fixes or suggestions just leave me a comment . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know am answering my own question but just in case someone else runs into the same issue . I was trying to figure where the issue is until i run into a post online saying that visual studio works best with Internet Explorer . Sorry i have no idea where i saw that post . Clear the browser data for Internet Explorer then change the start action to Microsoft Edge . That solved the problem for me .